# Selenium tests works in local but not in Gitlab CI

Tags: selenium, docker, spring-boot, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am currently working on a Java Spring Boot project which involves a classic backend/frontend architecture. I am trying to write some basic integration test by using the Selenium WebDriver.

The problem is that the tests I write pass without any problem on my local development machine but do not pass when I run them thorugh the continuous integration setup (Gitlab CI).

The code of the example test is the following:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ExampleTest {
    
    @LocalServerPort 
    private int port;
    
    WebDriver wd;
    
    @Test
    public void successfulLogin(){
        String url = "http://localhost:" + port;
        wd = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        wd.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        wd.get(url);
    }
}
```

The relative `gitlab-ci.yml` portion is:

```
stages:
  - test

maven-test:
  image: maven:3.5.0-jdk-8
  stage: test
  script: "mvn test -B -Dmaven.repo.local=/root/.m2/"
  only:
    - master
```

The CI has a single runner (version 9.5.0) with concurrency 1. It uses the `docker` executor with the `docker:stable` image. I don't know if it is needed, but it is running in `priviledged` mode.
When running the tests on the CI environment, they fail with the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

I have tried both with `url = "http://localhost:" + port` and `url =         InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() + ":" + port`, both passed locally, none passed in the CI environment.

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT: Alfageme suggested a more accurate testing methodology. On the same server on which the CI is running, I cloned my repository with `git clone` and then run the following command:

```
sudo gitlab-runner exec docker maven-test
```

The test passed without any problem. I am really running out of ideas, does someone have any?

Comment: Did you check if there is some firewall in place that your request is routed through? Did you try the IP of the server (127.0.0.1 in best case) as well or is your DNS properly configured?

Comment: Yes, I also tried with the ips, both with 127.0.0.1 and with the machine ip as given from `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()`. Both works in local, none works in the CI environment.
Firewalls should not be a problem, I think. Everything I am doing is happening inside the Docker container spawned by the Gitlab CI docker executor, right?

Comment: Have you tried to run in this maven container as well or just locally on your machine? I suppose the problem is more docker related than gitlab-ci related...

Comment: I too think it's more a Docker problem than else, or a problem between Docker and the CI. I will try now to run the test in a local container, I did not think about that :facepalm:

Comment: Ok, I have done some more tests. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Also a more-accurate way of running the tests locally would be to download and run locally (doesn't have to be in the actual, configured runner) the `gitlab-runner` binary on your repository: `gitlab-runner exec docker maven-test`(see https://bryce.fisher-fleig.org/blog/faster-ci-debugging-with-gitlabci/index.html for more info.) You'll be able to introspect the failed containers by restarting them afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, tomorrows I will definitely look more into this issue

Comment: I tried with the method suggested by you, @Alfageme: the tests pass without any problem

Comment: What is the docker runner configuration?

Comment: Did you get figure this out? I'm having the same exact issue.

Comment: Sorry, no. In the end we gave up on Selenium and started working with Cypress

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure why, but clearing the various `runner-XXXXX-project-21-concurrent-0-cache-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` docker containers on the CI machine seemed to have solved the issue.

---

EDIT: This fixed the issue only momentarely. The problem happened again, this time clearing the cache voulmes did not help. Anyone has any suggestion?